# ASP.NET MVC pass model to an html template without controllerContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to have an html template I'm using for emails. I want to pass a model to it, have it rendered and returned to a string variable.

How can I accomplish this? I'm sure I can use the rendering that comes with asp.net mvc.

I do not want to do this inside my controller or using the controllercontext object.

Comment: I've been trying to do this very thing for quite some time and I assure you it can be done, but the solution is not easy and it feels a bit "dirty". Have you looked into [NDjango](http://ndjango.org/index.php?title=NDjango_Home) or [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) as an alternative?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not do it inside the controller?

Comment: @Scott, a webservice might trigger the method to send email.

Comment: @Mitch Rosenbug, I want to use NDjango but it requires like 5 different dlls to do 1 thing....

Comment: what about using a display template for your model and then just calling `Html.DisplayForModel(model)` in your view? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450%28v=VS.98%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a comment from @Mitch Rosenburg as the answer:

I'm using [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) templates.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I found a library called [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) that I'm planning to use for a very similar feature in my own apps.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to send only the body up to a service layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like in the following method:

```
private string ViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) 
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

And in your action method you can use it like this

```
ViewToString("Index", model);
```

where model is the model that you want to send to your 'template'

Comment: Didn't see that you wanted to do this outside the controller. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing once, and I ended up using HttpWebRequest to "render" the view and capture the result as a string.

This solution came with a whole host of other issues (getting the authorization cookie, powering through our custom url security layer, etc), and it felt inefficient and sloppy, but deadlines are deadlines, right?

Code looked something like this:

```
public string GetEmailBody(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.